# Why such output of C program

Tags: c, initialization, comma-operator

I was trying to run following code and came across some results. Can somebody please explain:

```
int number = {12,13,14};
printf("%d",number);
```

Above code prints output as `12`. If I try to run the following code:

```
int number = (12,13,14);
printf("%d",number);
```

this prints output as `14`, but with following code it prints output as `12`:

```
int number;
number = 12,13;
printf("%d",number);
```

Comment: Only the second example even compiles for me, ANSI C on Windows.  On example 1 its a  Missing '}' on the first comma.  On example 3 its a Missing Identifier on 13.  What compiler are you using?    (Example 2 does match your results.)

Comment: You can try it here http://codepad.org/

Comment: Note, the first case is undefined behavior since since you are providing more values than objects.

Comment: It will not assign 12, i.e. first element to the `number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number = {12,13,14}` is scalar initialization, but you are providing more elements than what you should, compiler will throw a warning which, I assume, you have ignored and the first element 12 is assigned to variable `number`.

When you use `number = (12,13,14)`,

**comma (`,`) operator evaluates the first operand and discards the result, then evaluates the second operand and returns the result.**

So here 12 is discarded and 13 is evaluated to 13 and returned. Now this returned 13 value is first operand for next comma operator. 
Now, it will evaluate 13 to 13 and will discard this result 13 and will evaluate second operand i.e. 14 and will return the result as 14 which is assigned to variable `number`.

When you do following

```
  number = 12,13;
  printf("%d",number);
```

This will print 12, because precedence of `=` is greater than `,` so first `number = 12` will be evaluated and `=` return assigned value i.e. 12. 
Now comma operator got two operands retured value of `=` operation i.e. 12 and 13.
With comma operator 12 will be evaluated as 12 and discarded. 13 is evaluated and returned.
Returned to? Nobody. Not assigned to `number` because assignment is already executed.
So `number = 12,13;` looks like `(number=12),13;`

Try this as well.

```
   int num1,num2;
   num2 = (num1 = 13,14);
   printf("%d %d",num1,num2);
```

This will print `13 14` as per the argument given for earlier code output.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = {12,13,14};
```

`number` is an `int`, which doesn't expect an initalizer like this, so illegal C syntax.

```
int number = (12,13,14);
```

comma operator returns the right operand as the result, it's equivalent to `int number = ((12,13),14)`, so `number` has a value of `14`.

```
int number = 12,13;
```

This is an initialization, not assignment. So comma operator should n't be used here, illegal C syntax.

After your edit, this code

```
int number;
number = 12,13;
```

is an expression statement, it's a comma operator, the first operand an assignment `number = 12` which assigns `number` with `12` as side effect, the second operand `13` is an expression statement as well, which does nothing as it has no side effect.

Answer (score 0):

The first expression:

```
int number = {12,13,14};
```

is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if we look a the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *2* says:

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
>   being initialized.

the intitializer is two elements over in this case. The second case relies on the *comma operator* which section `6.5.17` paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The **left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression**; there is a
>   sequence point after its evaluation. Then the **right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value**.97

the second case:

```
int number = (12,13,14);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int number = ((12,13),14);
```

Following the rules laid out in `6.5.17` The result of `(12,13)` will be `13` and the result of `13,14` will be `14`. In the final case:

```
number = 12,13;
```

since `=` binds tighter(*has higher precedence*) than `,` the value `12` will be assigned to `number` and then `13` will be evaluated with no side effect.